# Socket project not connecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tkinter

I have a socket project running. This is the base project and some features.
This is server file:

```py
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave! Now type your name and press enter!", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name

    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
            broadcast(msg, name+": ")
        else:
            client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
            break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):  # prefix is for name identification.
    """Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""

    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)


clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = "192.168.43.67"
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

I added HOST ip manually getting from ifconfig.
and client file is:

```py
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import tkinter


def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    """This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  # For the messages to be sent.
my_msg.set("Type your messages here.")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  # To navigate through past messages.
# Following will contain the messages.
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=50, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

#----Now comes the sockets part----
HOST = input('Enter host: ')
PORT = input('Enter port: ')
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

When i run server and send to my friend my ip I get from ifconfig he can't connect yo my server.
I am sending wrong ip?
- Firewall desactivated

Comment: You bind your server program to an internal IP address `192.168.43.67` which cannot be accessed via internet.

Comment: which ip should I bind?

Comment: It depends on how your server is connected to outside (i.e internet).  If you have an static IP address assigned by your service provider, use that static IP address.  If your server is connected via router, then you need to setup a port forward in your router to forward any traffic from outside on port 33000 to your server, then you can use the internal IP address.